# Как достучаться до клиента без внешнего ip по RMI?

Tags: java, http, сеть, клиент-сервер, rmi

У сервера есть внешний ip-адрес, у клиентов нету. Мы хотим с сервера вызывать методы на машинах клиентов. Подскажите как реализовать данную процедуру. Знаю о WebSocket API, но хотелось бы не тратить время на HTTP, читал что это долго)

Answer (score 1):

По сути у вас есть единственный вариант - это периодически опрашивать клиентами сервер, адрес которого известен и считывать у него задания для себя. Если требуется интерактивность, то лучший вариант сокеты.